# Running a function while changing range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<input type="range">` on my site.

My function to listen to this change is called like so:

```
$("#selector").bind("change", function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

This does what I want it to do but it only happens when I release the range thumbnail I want the function to happen as I move the thumbnail not just when I release it, is this possible?

Comment: `.bind` is highly deprecated - use `.on`. Please create a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

---

Use `input` event instead.

Without jQuery you can do

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Or with jquery

```js
$('input').on('input', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="range" />
```